# Select Checkbox in Table using Java Script

Tags: javascript

I have to select only search results which is showing in tables and display selected checkbox details in text area.How to implement this in java script? I am trying below code.But it is not selecting checkboxes while clicking select all checkbox.

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytable");

for (var r = 1, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
  var test = table.rows[r].cells[1].innerHTML;

  if (test.indexOf(tabledata) >= 0) {
    table.rows[r].cells[0].checked = source.checked; //Not Working
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<table id="MyTable" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr class="info">
      <th style="width: 10px;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_selectall_b" onClick="selectAll(this)" />SA</th>
      <th>Parameter Name</th>
      <th>Quick view</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mcve]

Comment: What is `source`? Also, this code needs to run inside an event listener in order to happen when you click a button - otherwise it will always run as soon as the page loads.

Comment: Details i have posted below link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53606733/select-check-box-based-on-search-result-in-table-using-javascript

Comment: I am able to get value when i select SA checkbox (Checked with alert)but same values are not checked in table.

Comment: Please post your html as well. Especially the html with the element with id 'mytable'

Comment: yes.Added html code

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check the cell, not the checkbox inside the cell.

Find the checkbox first, then check it:

```
table.rows[r].cells[0].querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').checked = source.checked;
```

Also, make sure the id `mytable` matches with the one in your html. (`mytable` is not the same as `MyTable`)